# how to rename downloaded file via ajax

Tags: php, post, download

For downloading a file via ajax, i have this php code and it works fine

```
if($_POST['downloadfile']) {
    $downloadfile = $_POST['downloadfile'];
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= $downloadfile");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");  

    @readfile($downloadfile);
    exit;
}
```

The value of `$_POST['downloadfile']` is the path to the file ; like `uploads/image.jpg`

When downloading the file, the name of the file is created by the browser as `uploads_image.jpg`
How can i force the browser to give it only the name `image.jpg` ?

I tried this with below with `basename` but ofcourse, this is not working :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= basename($downloadfile"));
```

Comment: Modify that header line slightly so that a) the basename function is "seen" and executed  b) the file name is enclosed in quotes in case it has a space in the name ... `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($downloadfile) . '"');`

Comment: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg");`

Comment: @Dave works great! Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify that header line slightly so that a) the basename function is "seen" and executed b) the file name is enclosed in quotes in case it has a space in the name.

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($downloadfile) . '"');
```